# Scope variables in nested while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, scope, nested

Can anyone help me out on this one?

I need my program to recognize custID.  I compile and it says custID not declared in this scope.  I'm trying to read this from a text file.

```
while (infile)
{
    infile >> init;
    infile >> custID >> planType;

        while(init != '\n' || !'<eof>')
        {
            infile >> phone_num >> minutes >> texts >> gigs;

            stepOneTotal = stepOneFunc(planType , phone_num , minutes , texts , gigs);

            sum += stepOneTotal;

            counter += 1;
        }
                stepTwoFunc(custId , sum , acctData);
                stepThreeFunc(custID , planType , counter , sum);

                grandTotal += sum;
                counter = 0;
                sum = 0;                                            
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid the dots that show indentation, let the actual indentation show indentation. Having the dots there just makes it harder for us to copy the code snippet and try it out ourselves.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please elaborate? The scope of a variable is the scope where it's declared and all nested scopes inside that. That means if you declare `planType` before entering the outer loop, then the scope includes the outer as well as any inner loops or other blocks. Does your code not compile? What is your problem?

Comment: Correct... the code does not compile.  I didn't think there should be any issues.  When I compile an error comes up saying custID was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you seem to be using the results of the `>>` operators without testing whether they succeeded (which can lead to undefined behavior).  And of course, `!'<eof>'` will always be false.  (Formally, it has an implementation defined value, so we can't be sure without knowing the implementation.  But practically, I can't imagine an implementation where `'<eof>'` would be `0`.)

Comment: Don't post information such as code or error/warning messages as comments, please *edit your question* to include all relevant information.

Comment: You *have* declared the variables somewhere?

Comment: You use both `custId` and `custID`. I suspect one of them is wrong.

Comment: Jeez!  This is what happens when you code for 4 hours straight.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `planType` in the first `while` loop before you assign to it.